# RAID Controller - PERC H740P Adapter 8GB cache

Tags: storage, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid

The new Dell T440 server with PERC H740P RAID controller is only showing 4GB for cache memory size.

Does Dell have incorrect advertising on their website?
http://www.dell.com/learn/ca/en/cadhs1/campaigns/dell-raid-controllers

Comment: Are you sure the controller has the latest firmware? How do you found it only has 4GB of write back cache?

Comment: To view PERC H740P RAID controller cache:
Dell OpenManage Server Administrator -> system -> storage -> PERC H740P adapter -> Information/Configuration -> cache memory size: 4096MB

or
idrac9 -> storage -> controllers -> PERC H740P -> cache memory size: 4096MB

Answer (score 2):

I just got a hold of Dell. Dell said the H740P physically has 8GB of cache but only 4GB is available for use for now.

The other 4GB of cache will be available for use after Dell has sorted out the bugs. Dell expects to have the firmware released around March 2018 where all 8GB of cache will be available.

Comment: http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-PowerEdge-RAID-Controller-H740P.pdf

"H740P will ship with matching 8GB DRAM & NV Cache. 4GB will be enabled at launch with the additional 4GB enabled through a firmware release post launch"